# Specialization and separatedness

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was reading [a proof on the Stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0986) about a morphism of schemes $Y\to X$ (where $X$ has the property that every point of $X$ specializes to a unique closed point) when I came across the following assertion:

> As $Y\to X$ is a finite morphism, we see that the set of closed points $Y_0$
> of $Y$ is the inverse image of the set of closed points $X_0$ of $X$.
> Moreover, every point of $Y$ specializes to a unique point of $Y_0$ as (a)
> this is true for $X$ and (b) the map $X\to Y$ is separated.

The last point seems to be asserting that

*If $y_1\rightsquigarrow y_0$ and $y_1\rightarrow y_0’$ are specializations of $Y$ that are sent to the same specialization $x_1\rightsquigarrow x_0$ of $X$ under a separated morphism of schemes, then $y_0=y_0’$.*

This is very close to the valuative criterion of separatedness, but in order to conclude, I need something like ‘I can represent two specializations of the same point by two maps from the spectrum of the same valuation ring.’

Can you help me prove or disprove the italicized assertion, or provide me with a reference? Thanks!

Comment: Please consider restoring the original version of the question - it includes good context, while the current revision does not.

Comment: Sure..........!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The italicized statement is false. Take $X=\mathrm{Spec}\,\mathbb{Z}_5$, and $Y=\mathbb{A}^1_X$. Let $x_1,y_1$ be the generic points of $X,Y$; let $x_0$ be the maximal ideal of $X$ (the unique closed point), but let $y_0,y’_0 \in Y$ correspond to the distinct maximal ideals $(5,x)$ and $(5,x^2+x+1)$.